# tablesorter column with text and integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, integer, tablesorter

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j4zka86L/)
The model column is not sorted properly. Just because there is an integer in the column. Someone said that I can use the complex text extraction, but I don't know how. Can anyone help me? Your great help can help

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

// call the tablesorter plugin 
$("table").tablesorter({ 
    // define a custom text extraction function 
    textExtraction: function(node) { 
        // extract data from markup and return it  
        return node.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML; 
    } 
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the `86` is the very first cell in the column. So the auto-detection of parsers thinks that is a numeric column. To fix it just set the column parser to text. The easiest way to do it is to add a "sorter-text" class to the header.

Because the plugin only looks at the last cell of the column in the thead, you need to add the class to the "model" cell ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j4zka86L/2/)).

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td class='tablehover2 sorter-false' rowspan=2><a href='http://www.toyota.com.hk/cars/new_cars/index.aspx' target='_blank'> Toyota </a>
        </td>
        <td class='tablehover2 sorter-false'><a >Full Model List & Specifications</a>
        </td>
        <td class='tablehover2 sorter-false'><a> Price List</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- the parsers are set by the class names in this row -->
        <td class='tablehover sorter-text'>Model</td>
        <td class='tablehover'>Price</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

There is no need to set a `textExtraction` function:

```
$('#tablesorter').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blackice'
});
```